# The CDF of two tails of a a normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

[image]

I need the expression of the CDF of the shaded areas (A). After searching around, this is best I can come up with. I am wondering if it is correct?

$F(x) = \Phi(x)$ if $x<l$, $\Phi(l)$ if $l \leq x \leq u$, $\Phi(l) + \Phi(x) - \Phi(u)$ if $x > u$

Comment: I did not really understand what you mean by the "cdf of the shaded areas".

Comment: @Pohoua the CDF of this normal distribution where only the shaded area is considered?

Comment: But the area does not integrate to 1, it does not correspond to a pdf. Maybe rescaling it ?

Comment: Are you looking for the CDF of the density $f(x| x\leq l \cup x\geq u)$?

Comment: @gunes Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we'll normalize it to make it a PDF (let event $A$ be $X\leq l \cup X\geq U$):
$$f_X(x|A)=\frac{f_X(x)}{P(A)}=\frac{f_X(x)}{\Phi(l)+1-\Phi(u)}, \ \text{for } x\leq l \cup x\geq u, \text{else } 0$$

Call the denominator $Z$, then the CDF will only have an additional normalization constant:

$$F_X(x|A)=\begin{cases}\Phi(x)/Z &x\leq l\\ \Phi(l)/Z &l\leq x\leq u\\ (\Phi(x)-\Phi(u)+\Phi(l))/Z & x\geq u \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understand correctly, the Z term is the normalization factor to ensure that the f(x) is integrated to 1. Is that right?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Thank you again, @gunes. Since you are here, I would like to pick your brain a bit more on a somewhat related question. I am not sure if that is appropriate. If it is not, please let me know and I will start a new question.

The question is if there is any property that I can use to compare $\frac{\Phi(x)}{\Phi(l)+1-\Phi(u)}$ with $\frac{\Phi(x-h)}{\Phi(l-h)+1-\Phi(u-h)}$ where $h>0$, $l<0<u$, and $|l| > |u|$.

Comment: @gdsquare I couldn’t see a direct relation at first sight. If that’s important for you, you can ask it as a new question and give a link to this one as context. This way, more people will see it.